# $3$ Events addition rule probability problem

Tags: probability

[image]

The answer given in the porblem is (a) At least $76$%

However, following the formula given for $3$ event addition probability:

$P(A \cup B \cup C ) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) -  P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C).$

I got $(0.25+0.76+0.40)-(0.25$ $\cdot$ $0.76)-(0.25 $$\cdot$ $0.40)- (0.76 $$\cdot$ $0.4) - (0.25 $$\cdot$$ 0.76 $$\cdot$$ 0.40) = 0.759$

Why in this case the answer is at least $76$%? not at most $76$%?

Comment: Why did you put "$0.25\cdot0.76$" for $P(A\cap B)$? (And similarly for the other intersections.) This is wrong, and this is the reason why you got a wrong answer.

Answer (score 5):

A quick answer to your question: $P(A \cup B \cup C) \ge P(B) = 76\%$ since $B \subseteq A \cup B \cup C$.

Your mistake is due to the incorrect assumption on the [independence](/questions/tagged/independence) of events $A,B,C$.  (Hover your mouse onto the tag link and click on "info" to see that the equality $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ requires independence of $A$ and $B$.)  However, this is not given in the question, so your calculations for $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ are incorrect.

Comment: oh that makes sense, so because it's not given in the question that whether A B and C are independent of eachother, we can't even apply the addition formula for $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ .

Comment: @pino231 The inclusion-exclusion principle is always right.  This can be proved by induction.  Your mistake is to treat probability of intersection of events as product of events.

Comment: so more specifically, since we don't know about the whether A B and C are independence these parts wouldn't hold:  $P(A \cap B) -  P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$ ?

Comment: @pino231 Your calculations for each of these terms are incorrect, but the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability) is correctly quoted.

Answer (score 3):

Let's think in terms of words rather than math symbols first. $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ means the probability of event $A$ **or** $B$ **or** $C$ **or** some combination of $A,B,$ and $C$ occurring. If we just had two events $X$ and $Y$, the probability of $X$ or $Y$ happening is bounded below by the probability of $X$ happening. This is because if $X$ happens, then $(X$ or $Y)$ also happens. Similarly the probability of $X$ or $Y$ happening is bounded below by the probability $Y$ happening for the reason that if $Y$ happens, then $(X$ or $Y)$ also happens. For concreteness, you can try thinking about it where $X$ is the event of it raining tomorrow and $Y$ is the event you see two dogs tomorrow.

So similarly $P(A\cup B \cup C)\geq P(A)$, and also $P(A\cup B \cup C)\geq P(B)$ and also $P(A\cup B \cup C)\geq P(C)$ are all true. However, as $P(B)\geq P(A)$ and $P(B)\geq P(A)$ we have that $P(A\cup B\cup C)\geq P(B)$ captures all three inequalities.

Why is what you wrote false? Well, because you assumed $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. This is true when $A$ and $B$ are independent, which we do not know. In fact, since we don't know anything else, the only statement we can make is $P(A\cup B\cup C)\geq P(B)$ and so the correct answer is A.

Comment: this is a very intuitive way of thinking about this question!